# How to fulfill the conditions of the MIT license for a code contribution

Tags: licensing, mit, collaboration, combined-work

If I have a project licensed under the [MIT License](http://choosealicense.com/licenses/mit/), and I find a snippet of code I want to integrate into my project, also licensed under MIT, **how do I fulfill the conditions of the project the snippet originated from?**

My project has a license file in the root of the source code, as required by the MIT License.

From [choosealicense.com](http://choosealicense.com/licenses/mit/) under "How to apply this license":

> Create a text file (typically named LICENSE or LICENSE.txt) in the root of your source code and copy the text of the license into the file. Replace [year] with the current year and [fullname] with the name (or names) of the copyright holders.

If I want to incorporate someone's MIT licensed snippet, do I need to replace the license file? Do I need to add a license file?

Comment: You will find your answer here http://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/4508/5858. Other related question here: http://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4531/can-i-combine-multiple-2-clause-bsd-license-files-into-one