# How to use Sakai free template

Tags: licensing, website

I am very new to web dev and trying to use the Sakai react template, https://github.com/primefaces/sakai-react, as a starter to my startup project. Am I allowed to use it as much as I want for commercial use? Also, if I won't be publishing my code anywhere, how do I cite the Sakai MIT license? Or if I only want some component in it, is it wrong to copy and paste the code into my project? Thanks

Comment: The repository you link to is entirely under the MIT licence (or so it says).  Could you take a look at [this question](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/4506/458) and let us know if it deals with everyting else you wanted to know?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I think my question is just that if I am not publishing my code, how do I cite the MIT license. The question you link to is the case where they also want to publish the code. But what I want to do is just use some component from the template in my commercial app. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I repeat, could you check the linked question, and tell us what of your own question remains unanswered thereby?

Answer (score 2):

The MIT license allows you to do many things with the software. Examples listed are:
"use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software" along with the right to allow others to do the same or less if you are doing a commercial project and creating a proprietary license.
The MIT license only requires you to copy this license and the (C) line.

You can do this in a couple of ways:

1. by uploading the `NOTICES` file with full license.
2. By putting the license text and copyright notice in the files you use and copy from the repository
3. If you also share your project under the MIT license, just copy the copyright notice and add it as described [here](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/13412/how-to-put-copyright-notice-if-i-use-several-other-code-bases-mit/13536#13536).

I will not check the entire repository, but the repository has an MIT license and if there is no other license described in a file, then the file is legally subject to the MIT license.

You can use the code under the MIT license, commercial, non-commercial, private, public for any purpose provided you include attribution.
Theoretically, you're fine if you don't include a mention in your private project, but remember that this is a license that you have to respect, so it's better to put this `NOTICES` file in the project directory.

Edit: You are **NOT** allowed to omit attribution. It is not legal, but no one knows that you omit attribution if your project is private. De facto, many people omit attribution before they test whether code works for them.

**This is not legal advice**

Comment: So, just to clarify, I can use this Sakai code as a template for my commercial web app without any attribution if my project's code is not published, but if I want to be safe, I just have to add something like "This project utilizes Sakai-react template: MIT license, copyright notice: (C)". Is this correct? Also, can I remove the byPrimeReact at the bottom of the template. Thank you!

Comment: @IDontknow The MIT license itself does not use the word 'attribution', but what it says verbatim is pretty clear: "The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.". I.e., you must include the text itself as is, but thankfully it's pretty short, so it is not a big deal to include it. In what form you include it is up to you, based on the form of your software. Some Web developers include a menu somewhere which shows the license in the web page itself. Other interpretations may include it only as an HTML comment.

Comment: @IDontknow As for your other question, the MIT license specifically allows modifications.

Comment: Simplified but not fully legal correct: do whatever but copy full license file with copyright notice also in private projects.**this is not legal advice**